# When I try to run program from exe file coming up exception ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED

Tags: c++

If I run my program in visual studio program working good, but when I try to run from .exe file coming up exception: ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED

[image]

I found this exception in Shader.h file:

```
GLuint vertex, fragment;
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];
    // Vertex Shader
    vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex);
    // Print compile errors if any
    glGetShaderiv(vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
```

Why it happen, maybe I need some extra file in folder with .exe file?

Comment: This is a run-time error, and not really anything to do with C++. Add a tag to whatever library/framework you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the problem is, with only the information you provided. It might be, that the program can't find the shader source file (wrong path as you suspected). It also may happen due to there being a programming error in the shader source file – OpenGL shaders are loaded as source strings and compiled by the driver. It also might be, that the shader is written using a OpenGL version profile, that's not supported by your system (i.e. shader may be a written for a version higher than what your system can do).

Answer (score -1):

I found the reason why this happen, simply was missing file core.vs in folder with my exe file.